# Trouble aligning widget to the center

Tags: python, pyqt6

Here's the code that I am having trouble with. For some reason that i don't know why the logo is not centered. I even tried using the setAlignment on other widgets but their position does not change.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('My First App')
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(1100, 645))

        icon_path = relative_to_assets('icon.ico')
        icon = QIcon(str(icon_path))
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)

        self.center_window()

        background = QLabel(self)
        bg_path = relative_to_assets('background.png')
        bg_image = QPixmap(str(bg_path))
        background.setPixmap(bg_image)
        self.setCentralWidget(background)


        overlay = QLabel(self)
        overlay.setStyleSheet('background-color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 35px;')
        overlay.setFixedSize(QSize(790, 500))
        overlay.setGeometry(self.frameGeometry().width() // 2 - overlay.width() // 2, self.frameGeometry().height() // 2 - overlay.height() // 2, overlay.width(), overlay.height())

        logo = QLabel(overlay)
        logo_path = relative_to_assets('logo.png')
        logo_img = QPixmap(str(logo_path))
        logo.setPixmap(logo_img)
        logo.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter)


    def center_window(self):
        frame_geometry = self.frameGeometry()
        screen = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen()
        screen_geometry = screen.availableGeometry()
        center_point = screen_geometry.center()
        frame_geometry.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.move(frame_geometry.topLeft())

app = QApplication([])
primary_screen = MainWindow()
primary_screen.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: The alignment property of a label just aligns *its contents* within its geometry. By default, a QLabel with a QPixmap tries to resize itself to the size of the pixmap. Set a layout manager for `overlay` and add the logo with `addWidget(logo, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)`.